# Using Java NIO for thousands of outgoing connections

Tags: java, proxy, nio

I'm looking for a fast solution to check the availability of a proxies in a list (up to 10k).

Proxy is available if we can connect to it, so to check 10k proxies we have to make 10k requests. Since connection timeout is set to 10 seconds, requests should be parallel.

Here's how availability is checked now:

```
private boolean isAvailable(Proxy proxy) {
    try {
        URL u = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection(proxy);
        conn.connect();
        LOG.warn("Proxy " + proxy.address() + " is OK");
        conn.disconnect();
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.warn("Proxy " + proxy.address() + " is unavailable");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Running 10k threads in Java is not a good idea, and even the rational amount of 32 threads gives us the duration of (10.000 / 32) * 10 = 3100 seconds.

So I think that Java NIO with selectors is the best option here, but I do not remember examples in tutorials, that were intended to scale that much. I guess that third-party libraries like netty could solve this task easily, but I'd like to see how it can be done nicely with pure java.

Also, is there any threshold for my scenario because of resource usage? Are client connections resource consuming, so it would be better to use only 500 simultaneous requests? Is there a theoretical maximum (besides number of ports) for this scenario?

Comment: What would an example that is intended to scale look like? As opposed to a normal example? You're looking for something that doesn't exist. All NIO code scales. If you have a real question that isn't just a request for an offsite resource, please ask it, but this isn't one.

Comment: @EJP example in tutorials usually say: "here are three channels and one thread on a selector, everything is nice", but I'm not sure that one thread is enough for 5000 channels. also, there is a question about resource consumption.

Comment: Would you really want to do 10000 all at once in parallel?   You're program might not be the bottleneck in that scenario.  10 threads with 100 selectors per thread in a loop 10x sounds more reasonable to me but that depends on your requirements.

Comment: @JJF i need it as quick as possible, this is init phase of a program, number of threads is not limited.

Comment: @AdamSkywalker have at then as they say.  The only way you're going to find out if you can wait on 5000 selectors is to try it.  Everything takes resources, there are no limits I am aware of.  You've got a somewhat unique situation here and the only way you're going to find out what works is to try a few experiments.   Good luck.